# Restangular set the correct ID

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have the problem that the API Im working against always returns the data wrapped inside an array.

So if I call GET api/companies/1/jobs/1 the response looks like this

```
{
data: [
  {
   id: 1
   name: "blabla"
  }
 ]
}
```

When I want to update this job and sent a put the URL is being build wrongly.

Instead of PUT api/companies/1/jobs/1 the request is sent to api/companies/1/jobs and gets rejected.

I have tried the following

```
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
          id: "data[0].id"
        });
```

but unfortunately this does not resolve my problem.

Is there any way to make this work with API being setup as it is?